# custom routes in rails: creating a link that throws each project with `project_id` to some `controller`

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

Suppose I have a `project` model and that I want to create a link that throws each project with `project_id` to some `controller` in `projects_controller`. I tried this

```
resources :projects do
    member do
      get :controller
    end
end
```

Does this work? Does the url `controller_project_url` is correct?

Comment: check the output of `rake routes` and see!

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you're asking. Is `controller` another resource or do you want to add an action called "controller" to your projects_controller? Also, as @sevenseacat said, run `rake routes` to confirm your available routes.

Comment: @mmichael yes indeed I want to add an action called "controller" to your projects_controller.

Comment: Then it should work. Can you confirm the route when you run `rake routes`? It should be `/projects/:id/controller`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @AmitThawait, this should suffice. Btw, with your routes, you should have some line like this, when running `rake routes`

```
controller_project GET    /projects/:id/controller(.:format)                               projects#controller
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to write `resources :projects` in your routes.

You can read more about routes in rails from http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

#### update :

Well, I would say its not a good idea to name a action as `controller`, you should name it in such a way that it should tell its behaviour.

What you have written routes is correct.